# Ruby (Rack) application could not be started error message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, terminal, redis, resque

my ruby application was working fine until earlier this week, the system crashed, and now I get an error message on the page...

Error message:
**Failed to connect to a master node at localhost:27017 (Mongo::ConnectionFailure)**

Exception class:
**PhusionPassenger::UnknownError**

Application root:
**/home/deploy/www/gm-git**

The system is set up as such...

• Ruby on Rails 3.0.8
• Mongoid 2.0.2
• Redis & Resque for background processing

I have tried the following boot sequence but withou success...

```
/opt/redis/redis-server
/opt/mongodb/bin/mongod --force --logpath /opt/mongodb/bin
rake environment rescue:workers
touch /home/proyectos/gm/test_git/goldenmile
```

I have updated this many times to for example

```
/opt/redis/redis-server
/opt/mongodb/bin/mongod --fork --logpath /opt/mongodb/bin
/opt/mongodb/bin/mongod --repair
rake environment rescue:workers
touch /home/proyectos/gm/test_git/goldenmile
```

But I get error messages in the terminal such as

```
/opt/mongodb/bin/mongod --start
ERROR: unknown option start

/opt/mongodb/bin/mongod --status
ERROR: unknown option status

/opt/mongodb/bin/mongod start
Invalid command: start

/opt/mongodb/bin/mongod/ --logpath /opt/mongodb/bin
-bash: /opt/mongodb/bin/mongod/: Not a directory

/opt/mongodb/bin/mongod/ --logpath /opt/mongodb/bin/mongod/
-bash: 2b.: command not found

/opt/mongodb/bin/mongod/ --logpath /opt/mongodb/bin/mongod
-bash: /opt/mongodb/bin/mongod/: Not a directory
```

Any help/directions would be most useful

Answer (score 0):

The Mongo::ConnectionFailure error for localhost:27017 is typical when **mongod** is not running.  You should check for this using the **ps** command, restart mongod if necessary, and then run the **mongo** shell.  If the mongo shell reports "Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1 shell/mongo.js:84" then go back and check the status of your mongod server process.

The following lines are suspicious.

```
/opt/mongodb/bin/mongod --fork --logpath /opt/mongodb/bin
/opt/mongodb/bin/mongod --repair
```

It appears that you are trying to run the mongod server and repair at the same time.  The repair attempt will bail out if mongod is already running, and I'm guessing that you really intended to run it before starting db service.  If you are on a 64-bit platform, journaling is on by default and you should not do a repair to recover a consistent state, see http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Durability+and+Repair

Also, repair can take a long time, and during this time, you cannot start another mongod for db service.  I suspect that this is your underlying problem - that repair was running, causing attempts to start db service to fail.

Regardless, it appears that **mongod** is not running.  Options like  --start, --status, start are all unknown as stated, and mongod also prints a full list of options for each of these errors.  Having a trailing slash after a shell command (after mongo) is telling the OS to look for a directory.  Did you try to execute mongod in the shell with no options?  What happens?  You need to get mongod running as a db server (not repair) and should verify that it is up and that you can connect using the **mongo** shell before you go any further.

Let us know how it works out.

Comment: Hi, I have had some success, I used...

root@XXXX:~# /opt/mongodb/bin/mongod --fork --logpath /opt/mongodb/db.log
root@XXXX:~# forked process: 2579
all output going to: /opt/mongodb/db.log

Comment: However, I now get the following error in the next part of the sequence...

root@XXXX:~# rake environment resque:workers
rake aborted!
No Rakefile found (looking for: rakefile, Rakefile, rakefile.rb, Rakefile.rb)
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2367:in `raw_load_rakefile'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2007:in `block in load_rakefile'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2058:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2006:in `load_rakefile'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:1991:in `run'
/usr/local/bin/rake:31:in `<main>